# xinitrc: starting xterm with tmux causes all windows to share same geometry

Tags: xorg, x11, tmux, window-manager, window-geometry

I have xterm with tmux open upon startup of X11 with the following line in my xinitrc file: `xterm -e tmux &`

However the `-e tmux` causes all windows to assume the geometry of the first -geometry attribute in the file, even if I separately define the geometry of the xterm window.  Enclosing in quotes or grave accents does not remedy the situation.

If I use tmux before starting X11 (i.e. execute then exit tmux), then the xterm window opens at the default geometry as it should. Restarting X11 causes the problem to return.

Suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

My entire xinitrc file:

`xsetroot -solid black`
`xstatbar &`
`xconsole -geometry -20-40 &`
`xterm -e tmux &`
`exec cwm`

At the moment all windows are at -20-40.  I'm running OpenBSD 5.4 on amd64 hardware.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on OpenBSD-current/amd64 (December 2016, post release 6.0). The xterms are of the default size, and specifying separate geometries for them will put them in their correct locations.